# How to get rid of yahoo search in firefox browser?

Tags: firefox

I have deleted the yahoo search in the my firefox browser search button. When I type some wrong url in the browser, I am getting yahoo search results. How to get rid of that?. My default search engine, I set was google.

screen shot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yFiL.jpg
I want to get rid of that yahoo search thing.

Comment: Katkov gave perfect answer. Folks! Release this question from 'hold'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type “about:config” into the address bar and accept the warning. Search for "browser.search.defaultenginename" in the search area. Change this to the search engine you want

See [this thread](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/968367) on the Mozilla support site or [this step by step guide](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Browser%27s-Default-Search-Engine)

Comment: As it is, this link-only answer is not quite appropriate for StackOverflow. Consider pasting the relevant details from those sites into your answer, in case one day those links no longer work.

Comment: Worked like Charm! Thanks Katkov.